# How can I use an object from node in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I want to use an object created in node in my Angular application. Something like,

In Node

```
# server.js
const app = express();
app.use('/', () => {
   const foo = {name: 'hello'};
   app.send('index.html', {
      foobar: foo,
   });
});
```

In Angular

```
# my.service.ts
export class MyService {
    constructor(private request: Request) {
        const { foobar } = this.request;
        console.log(foobar) // {name: 'hello'}
    }    
}
```

I want to prevent using handlebars and setting global variables on the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not so many ways how initial data can be passed from server to client. As long the client-side application is being bundled and cannot make use of dynamically loaded JS modules (SystemJS, native, etc.), data can be provided by the server as global variable or through a cookie.

Considering that cookies have limitations and require additional actions to unserialize data on client side, global variable is the obvious choice. This is how it's done in real-world Angular applications. A variable can have 'special' name to avoid name collisions, yet it should be defined in HTML response:

```
<script>
window.__APPDATA__ = { foobar: {name: 'hello'} };
</script>
```

Data can also be provided through root component attribute. This requires additional actions as well. It should be serialized and escaped:

```
<app data="{&quot;foobar&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;hello&quot;}}"></app>
```

It can be retrieved with `Attribute` (there are no `Input`s for root components) and deserialized in component class.